# Ошибка в запросе к БД: "Unable to save result set"

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Есть запрос

```
  "SELECT datacenter.id, text, 
  (SELECT avatar FROM massage WHERE id_finish= '$id')
  AS finishavatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname 
  FROM massage JOIN datacenter 
  ON datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE  massage.id_start= '$id'"
```

Он выдает ошибку

> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in  Y:\home\localhost\www\u\massage_my.php on line 52
> Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значит такой вопрос не возможен физически, судя по тому что я вижу у тебя дублируются id_finish(т.е. id_finish не является уникальным), а это обязательное условие для выполнения подобного запроса.

По факту у тебя в под-запросе

---

```
SELECT avatar FROM massage WHERE id_finish= '$id'
```

---

Возвращается больше одного значения, поэтому и возникает ошибка, если у тебя в БД хранится время сообщения. Конечно можно, чтобы не-было ошибки, написать как-то типа

---

```
 SELECT datacenter.id, text, 
   (SELECT avatar FROM massage WHERE id_finish= '$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
      AS finishavatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname 
           FROM massage JOIN datacenter 
                ON datacenter.id = massage.id_finish WHERE  massage.id_start= '$id'
```

---

Но **ожидаемого** результата этот запрос не принесет, тебе необходимо думать как реализовать связь. а лучше вообще изменить структур твоей базы данных. Если кратко подсумировать - в твоем случае сделать запрос который ты хочешь невозможно по причине отсутствия связи

Comment: зайди в ВК

Answer (score 0):

```
> fetch first 1 rows only
```

добавь в конце, должно работать

Comment: Ошибки не будет, но работать так как должно тоже не будет :)